# Obtener información de ifconfig y camuflar función ping

Tags: linux, bash, ping, red

He implementado un script en bash para autodetección de sistemas por ethernet. Trabajo con Linux. Tengo dos preguntas al respecto:

**1. ¿Es posible camuflar la información de salida de `ping`?**

Hago varios request distintos mediante la función `ping`, y la verdad es que emborrona bastante le terminal con la información que escupe la función `ping` al ser llamada. Me gustaría que, por así decirlo, dicha función estuviese "camuflada".

**2. ¿Cómo consigo información de la función `ifconfig`?**

En cada request que hago debo cambiar el interfaz de red. Actualmente lanzo un `ifconfig` para que aparezca por pantalla la interfaz de red ethernet, y el usuario debe ingresar dicho nombre. El código es el siguiente:

```
ifconfig
read -p "Interfaz de red: " INTERFAZ_RED
ifconfig $INTERFAZ_RED $IP netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Me gustaría saber si el nombre de la interfaz de red es posible guardarlo en una variable que posteriormente se utilice para configurar de manera automática la red.

Si necesitáis más información decídmelo en los comentarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Si no quieres que el resultado de `ping` se muestre en la salida estándar, puedes probar algo como

```
ping [opciones] $IP 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

2. Para las interfaces, estás suponiendo que sólo hay una y muy seguramente habrá varias. ¿Cuál debería elegir tu script? ¿Tu script sólo funciona en sistemas sin systemd (porque `net-tools` ya no está instalado en muchas versiones y ahora es con `ip addr sh`)?

PD. El nombre no es porque sea vm o no, se debe a cambios en cómo udev nombra las interfaces [(fuente)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/311844/130378)

```
enp0s10:
| | |
v | |
en| |   --> ethernet
  v |
  p0|   --> número de bus (0)
    v
    s10 --> número de slot (10)
```

Seguramente la wifi debe salir como `wlp0s1` o algo similar. Ya ahí tienes info de lo que estás buscando. Prueba con grep o awk para intentar extraer la info que buscas :)

Comment: Probaré con la opción que me dices. Cuando dices `algúnRecurso` te refieres a las opciones? Lo tengo configurado para que sólo transmita 1 paquete (`ping -c 1 $IP`) En tu ejemplo, dónde pongo la IP y las opciones? Respecto al la segunda pregunta, me salen 2 interfaces, una ethernet y otra wifi. Quiero que escoja la de ethernet. Pero quiero que sea "automático e inteligente", ya que en algunas máquinas es `eth1`, en máquinas virtuales es `enp0s3` (por ejemplo), etc...

Comment: Respuesta editada

Comment: Vale, perfecto! Una última cosa.. Tenía en mente emplear `grep` o algo parecido una vez que pueda extraer la información de la interfaz, pero mi pregunta es si hay algún modo de poder extraer ese nombre `eth1`, `enp0s10`, etc. Una vez que tenga eso es sencillo "discriminar" entre una u otra

Comment: Pues a mí se me ocurre (valiente ocurrencia, je) una expresión regular que capture lo que salga con esa estructura y guarde el primer match en una variable, por ejemplo... ya esa es una pregunta diferente :D

Comment: jajaja las ocurrencias valientes son las que triunfan. Muchas gracias! Marco la respuesta como respondida por la ayuda del `ping`. Muchas gracias!